# C++ retrieving multiple types of data from a class

Tags: c++, json, class, types, return-value

I have made a class that holds all the data that is read from a file.

```
class Entry
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    std::vector<std::string> arrayString;
    std::vector<Entry> arrayEntry;
    enum dataValueCheck
    {
        str,arrStr,arrEnt
    };

    dataValueCheck dataValue;
public:
    Entry(std::string key, std::string value)
        :key(key), value(value)
    {
        dataValue = str;
    }
    Entry(std::string key, std::vector<std::string> value)
        :key(key), arrayString(value)
    {
        dataValue = arrStr;
    }
    Entry(std::string key, std::vector<Entry> value)
        :key(key), arrayEntry(value)
    {
        dataValue = arrEnt;
    }

    std::string getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T getData()
    {
        switch (dataValue)
        {
        case Entry::str:
            return value;
        case Entry::arrStr:
            return arrayString;
        case Entry::arrayEntry:
            return arrayEntry;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

};
```

This file is basically a JSON file and resembles this structure.

```
{
Name:Test,
Arr_Item:[1,2,3],
Sub_Item:
    {
    Item1 : [0,1,2,3],
    Item2 : [4,5,6],
    }
}
```

I have it reading the data in just fine. Where I am getting stuck is retrieving the data using the `getData` function that is part of the class. When I try and use a `template` I get an "illegal case" error. How can I get the data out of this class?

**UPDATE**

I have a `vector` filled with the Entry classes. When I try and access it like this:

```
    std::vector<Entry> DB;

    std::string test = DB[0].getData<std::string>();
```

It should return "Test", but instead I get this error:

```
1>C:\Dev\Playground\Playground\src\Main.cpp(454,1): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::vector<Entry,std::allocator<Entry>>' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>C:\Dev\Playground\Playground\src\Main.cpp(454,4): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Comment: First, your enum `dataValueCheck` doesn't have `Entry::arrayEnt`, I think you mean `Entry::arrEnt`

Comment: You could drop the template and return a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: Can you post the exact & complete error you get?

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde I have updated it to show the error.

Comment: @WagnerPatriota You are right. I did have that mistake, but updating didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: @PaulSanders I will try and edit my code to see if I can get a `variant` type to work. Thank you.

Comment: @laxer Might you need `T getData(dataValueCheck  v)` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all gets very easy if you drop the template and return a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) from `getData`.  It gets easier still if you store the value in `Entry` as a `std::variant` in the first place (you only need to store one of the types in any particular instance of `Entry`, right?).

Here's a fully worked-up example.  Note that I pass the parameters to the constructor by const reference to avoid unnecessary copies; you might also return (const) references from `getKey` and `getData` for the same reason:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Entry
{
    using EntryType = std::variant <std::string, std::vector <std::string>, std::vector <Entry>>;
    
    std::string key;
    EntryType value;
        
public:
    template <typename T>
    Entry(const std::string &key, const T &value) : key(key), value(value) {}

    std::string getKey() { return key; }

    EntryType getData() { return value; }
};

int main() {
    Entry e { "key", "string value" };
    std::cout << std::get <std::string> (e.getData ());
}
```

Comment: This is great! I was over complicating it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  `std::variant` is _awesome_.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData` function did not handle for the default case in `switch` statement. You can either return something such as nullptr or throw an exception in case

```
template <typename T = nullptr_t>
T getData()
{
    switch (dataValue)
    {
    // Cases
    default:
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing the the code still produces the same error

Comment: @laxer how did you create your DB ?? Looking at the errors that mean the element has `arrStr` but tried to get `str`. The types is not correct

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that not all return values can be validly converted to `T` for any particular `T`.

Let's take the example from your posted example. We have this expression:

```
DB[0].getData<std::string>();
```

If we subsitute `std::string` for `T`, this is what `getData()` looks like:

```
std::string getData()
{
    switch (dataValue)
    {
    case Entry::str:
        return value;
    case Entry::arrStr:
        return arrayString;
    case Entry::arrayEntry:
        return arrayEntry;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Only the `Entry::str` case is valid here as it actually returns a `std::string`. The other cases return either a `std::vector<std::string>` or a `std::vector<Entry>`, neither of which can be converted to a `std::string`.

There are many ways to resolve this, but probably the best is to recognize that `Entry` is basically a key mapped to a `std::variant`. If `getData()` returned a `std::variant`, you would avoid many potential pitfalls while relying on a standard type. Alternatively, if you want to stick with your current approach, you would need some way of returning the right value based on `T`, not (only) based on `dataValue`. I.e., you need some way of handling the possibility that `T` does not match the expectation set by `dataValue`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to returning a variant, you could use `if constexpr` in `getData`

```
template <typename T>
T getData()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) { 
        return (dataValue == Entry::str) ? value : throw type_error(dataValue, Entry::str);
    } else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<std::string>>) { 
        return (dataValue == Entry::arrStr) ? arrayString : throw type_error(dataValue, Entry::arrStr);
    } else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<Entry>>) { 
        return (dataValue == Entry::arrEnt) ? arrayEntry : throw type_error(dataValue, Entry::arrEnt);
    } else {
#error Invalid type requested for Entry::getData
    }
}
```